# How can I make a circular page? (when scrolled to the end of page content, page adds the beginning of conten to the bottom and so forth)

Tags: javascript, html, css, infinite-scroll

I am currently making a portfolio, in which I have Comic-books that use circular storytelling - meaning the story always repeats itself. Where it ends it begins from new.
I know how vertical scrolling works, but now I wish to have the page infinitely scroll as you could read the comic over and over. Ideally, this would work seamlessly (without skipping around inside the page).

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how I can do this with HTML and CSS, or if need be also with javascript?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome AMNOFFICIAL! We always love to see some effort before we solve a problem. What ideas do you have for accomplishing this? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the structure of a repeating comic in the portfolio; does one comic use multiple images/frames on a page that you create and scroll through, or just one large image with the entire comic in it? Do you have an html example of a page with a comic?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/N9PWn/ maybe you can take something from here. :-?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @chrisbyte yes, the comic should use several image files, but also at least one paragraph.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Well I'm a newby, so I hoped someone has done something similar like this before. I have not tried anything yet because I do not know how such a thing could be done at all. I have had one idea for accomplishing it: You make a normal page, but when you are nearing the end you start "rendering" the beginning of the page right after the end again. I have no Idea how this could be done, especially if you wish to keep links functional. I have read solutions for adding new content seamlessly, but that is not required here since content of page does not change.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm sorry this question doesn't meet the requirements you seek in a question on Stack Overflow. Could you tell me what I could add to this question so you can answer it?
If it is too broad, how else should I find out about it then to ask?

Comment: @MaraBlack this could be something! Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually the thing I was looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/N9PWn

Thank You Mara

```
window.verticalScroller = function($elem) {
var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
var temp = -1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
if(top < temp) {
    top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
    $elem.css("top", top);
}
$elem.animate({ top: (parseInt(top)-60) }, 600, 'linear', function () {
  window.verticalScroller($(this))
});}


$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 0;
$("#verticalScroller > div").each(function () {
      $(this).css("top", i);
      i += 60;
      window.verticalScroller($(this));
});});
```